# How to change backgound of second/third etc tag from angular.element [jqLite]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, element, jqlite

I can get all `<mark>` elements and set them background like:

```
element.find('mark').css( "background-color", "red");
```

But how can I set background just for second or third argument (third mark), i tried something like this:

```
element.find('mark')[3].css( "background-color", "red");
(element.find('mark')[3]).css( "background-color", "red");
```

Above example doesn't work, please help me

Greetings
rizon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a jQuery object by index it returns the underlying DOMElement at that index. The issue you have there is that DOMElements do not have a `css()` method. Instead you should use `eq()` to get the element at the required index wrapped in a jQuery object. Try this:

```
element.find('mark').eq(3).css('background-color', 'red');
```